# MetroFramework: Changing Form Color

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using MetroFramework and I'm trying to change the color of the form. Unfortunately, the form by default provides only two "themes", light and dark.

I've tried: `this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(180, 50, 50);`, with no success.

I've found people using XML files to change the color, but I'm assuming thats with WPF, but I'm using WinForms.

Anyone know how to change the form color using the MetroFramework?